# double sum of two binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

the question asks us to compute the following sum :

> $$\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j} \sum_{j \leq n} (C_i \hspace{0.05cm}+ \hspace{0.05cm}C_j)^2$$

I honestly don't know what to do with the squareed terms $C_i^2 $ and $C_j ^2$.

I reached upto the point where I could evaluate the sum of $C_i C_j$

I got the following expression :
$$\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j} \sum_{j \leq n} (C_i \hspace{0.05cm} ^2+ \hspace{0.05cm} C_j \ ^2)\hspace{0.05cm}+ \hspace{0.05cm} (2^n)^2 \hspace{0.05cm}- \hspace{0.05cm} ^{2n}C_n$$

**it comes from the part where we use the formula
$$\sum \text {2 at a time } = (a+b+c+d .....)^2 - (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2.....)$$

So, now how do I solve it ? what do i do with the first sum term ?

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{0\leq i\leq n~~} \sum_{0\le j\leq n} (C_i+C_j)^2\\\displaystyle= \sum_{0 \leq i \leq j~} \sum_{j \leq n} (C_i + C_j)^2+ \sum_{0 \leq j \leq i~} \sum_{i \leq n} (C_i + C_j)^2- \sum_{i=j} (C_i + C_j)^2\\\displaystyle=2\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j~} \sum_{j \leq n} (C_i +C_j)^2-\sum_{i=j} (C_i+ C_j)^2$

Comment: whoa ! what did you do there @Asher2211 ?

Comment: the adding and subtracting, is it valid ? one has double sum other has single

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j~} \sum_{j \leq n} (C_i + C_j)^2= \sum_{0 \leq j \leq i~} \sum_{i \leq n} (C_i + C_j)^2$

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j~} \sum_{j \leq n} (C_i + C_j)^2$ includes all the cases with $i\le j$ and $ \displaystyle\sum_{0 \leq j \leq i~} \sum_{i \leq n} (C_i + C_j)^2$ includes all the cases with $j\le i$. We have counted the case $i=j$ in both the sums so we subtracted $\displaystyle\sum_{i=j} (C_i + C_j)^2$. This is basically like the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: oh yeah yeah. im slowly getting it. let me wait for answers too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with
$$P_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^n (A_i+ A_j)^2=(2n+2)\sum_{k=0}^{n}A_k^2+2\left(\sum_{k=0}^n A_k\right)^2,~~~~(1)$$
Then
$$T_n=\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j} \sum_{j \leq n} (A_i+ A_j)^2=\frac{1}{2}[P_n+4\sum_{k=0}^{n}A_k^2]=(n+3)\sum_{k=0}^{n} A_k^2+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} A_k\right)^2~~~~(2)$$
One may check that if $A_k=k$, we get $T_0=0, T_1=5, T_2=34, T_3=120.$

In the OP's case (2) gives
$$S_n=\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j} \sum_{j \leq n} \left[{n \choose i} \hspace{0.05cm}+ \hspace{0.05cm}{n \choose j}\right]^2=(n+3){2n \choose n}+2^{2n}~~~~(3)$$
When you pot $n=0$, you get $S_0=4,S_1=12,S_2=46$, rightly.

Comment: The logic seems okay to me but the answer doesn't.
Here's the answer which was released  : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uXxIexAdHzNN_uGR6fQQxXATDE4zC48K/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct. The simple test is for $n=0$ one should get $S=4$

Comment: yes i agree with you

Answer (score 0):

The problem becomes much simpler if we visualize the indices as lattice points in the $ij$-plane.

Consider the lattice points within and on the square with vertices $(0, 0)$, $(n, 0)$, $(0, n)$ and $(n, n)$. And to each point $(i, j)$, assign the value $(C_i + C_j)^2$. The problem asks us to compute the sum of the assigned values within and on the triangle with vertices $(0, 0)$, $(0, n)$, $(n, n)$. Since the values are symmetric along the line $i=j$, and it is easy to find the sum of $(C_i + C_j)^2$ when $i=j$, it suffices to focus on the entire square. That is, to evaluate the sum $(C_i + C_j)^2$ over all indices $i=0, \dotsc, n$ and $j=0, \dotsc, n$.

It is now quite easy to see that this sum over all indices is equal to

$$2n\cdot C^{2n}_n + (2^n)^2.$$

Now, we just need to subtract off the diagonal and we are done.

Comment: For $n=0$ your expreesion gives 1, but it should be 4.

Comment: Sorry, your solution is not correct.